# Error messages in jQuery's XML parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, error-handling

I was wondering what kind of information jQuery provides when parsing XML. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/1e0setq1/).

There is the error as a whole:

> Error: Invalid XML: This isn't valid XML at all.

Or you can extract the message with `e.message`:

> Invalid XML: This isn't valid XML at all.

But what other methods are there? Is it for instance possible to only get the "Invald XML" bit? I've been googling for ages, but can't find any documentation on this.

Also, does jQuery generate these error fallbacks, or does jQuery simply utilises the browser's XML handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer(s) to your question is contained right in the jQuery source code:

```
jQuery.parseXML = function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
};
```

Yes it is using browser methods and

No, you can't isolate the specific problem without rewriting the method.

**[Helpful jQuery Source Viewer with method search](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.parseXML)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    (function($) {
    jQuery._parseXML = function ( data ) {
        var xml, tmp, e, msg;
        if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
                tmp = new DOMParser();
                xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );
            } else { // IE
                xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
                xml.async = "false";
                xml.loadXML( data );
            }
        } finally {
            e = $(xml).children().contents().filter(function(i, el) {
                  return $(el).is("parsererror")
                });
                // if `parsererror` element `length` > 0
                // return `msg` , else return `undefined`
                msg = !!e.length 
                      // define error `msg` here
                      ? [ e.text()
                         , e.next()[0].previousSibling.nodeValue
                         , e.next()[0].outerHTML
                         , e.next()[0] 
                        ] 
                      : undefined;
        }
        // if `msg` !== undefined , return `msg` , else return `xml`
        return msg !== undefined ? msg : xml
    }
    }(jQuery));
```

```js
(function($) {
        jQuery._parseXML = function ( data ) {
            var xml, tmp, e, msg;
            if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
                    tmp = new DOMParser();
                    xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );
                } else { // IE
                    xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
                    xml.async = "false";
                    xml.loadXML( data );
                }
            } finally {                
                e = $(xml).children().contents().filter(function(i, el) {
                      return $(el).is("parsererror")
                    });
                msg = !!e.length 
                      // define error `msg` here
                      ? [ e.text()
                         , e.next()[0].previousSibling.nodeValue
                         , e.next()[0].outerHTML
                         , e.next()[0] 
                        ] 
                      : undefined;
            }
            // if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement 
            //      || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
            // jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
            // }
            return msg !== undefined ? msg : xml
        }
        }(jQuery));

console.log(
  $._parseXML("<node>abc123</node>")
  , $._parseXML("<node>abc123<node>")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```